# What is the difference between "intraphoton" and "interphoton" entanglement?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, photonics, orbital-angular-momentum

I am trying to better understand the following:

> What is the difference between Intraphoton Entanglement and Interphoton Entanglement?

I am new in this field and i want to proceed some work on swapping of Intraphoton Entanglement to Interphoton Entanglement.

Comment: where is this terminology from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Intraphoton entanglement** uses the degrees of freedom from one photon only to create entanglement. So, here either [polarization and linear momentum](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10990969) or [polarization and angular momentum](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys919) can be used to create entanglement. **Interphoton entanglement** is the entanglement created between 2 spatially separated photons. So, naturally latter is less stable than former. For this reason, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.0425) used former as a resource to create latter.

Comment: "*So, naturally latter is less stable than former*" this seems quite a generic statement. Have you got a source for that? One can think of all sorts of type of entanglement shared by different photons or internal dofs of a single photon, and I would expect the stability of which to be highly dependent on the experimental circumstances

Comment: Yeah, my comment was a bit generic. I should have specified it with respect to the discussion of degrees of freedom. To add to my previous comment, according to the third paper I linked, two degrees of freedom within one photon are easier to maintain than between two photons.